# Restrict the ECB file tree to files known by projectile OR files not in my .gitignore?

Tags: projectile, ecb

As I am working more and more with these modern "compiles to Javascript" languages my ECB files view becomes more and more cluttered. Projectile seems to get things right out of the box by ignoring everything that is part of my `.gitignore` file, can I tell ECB to do something similar? Specifically I want to get rid of those `.js` and `.js.map` files.

[image: Unneeded .js and .map files]

I am aware of `M-x customize-group RET ecb-sources` and `source-file-regexps` but that seems like a global solution to a local problem: In other projects I need to see files with these extensions.